# VBA EXCEL Macro code execution interruption using a Column reorder Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm using the following coding for column re-ordering

```
Dim search As Range
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim colOrdr As Variant
Dim indx As Integer

colOrdr = Array("fullDt", "branchName", "mediumDesc", "successInd", "accountNumber", "secondaryAccountNumber", "executingPartyName", "executingPartyNumber", "tranType", "currencyAmount", "cashAmount", "mechanism", "presenterName", "transactionDescription", "foreignCurAmt", "foreignCurrencyCd", "remitterName", "beneficiaryName", "countryFlow", "transactionReferenceNumber") 

cnt = 1


For indx = LBound(colOrdr) To UBound(colOrdr)
    Set search = Rows("1:1").Find(colOrdr(indx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not search Is Nothing Then
        If search.Column <> cnt Then
            search.EntireColumn.Cut
            Columns(cnt).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
Next indx
```

It was working fine yesterday, but when the running macros today, i get the prompt screen with "code execution has been interrupted".

If I keep pressing continue, the code runs through and completes, If i Debug, it goes to one of these two lines of code

```
Columns(cnt).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I have other users using the same macro without issue, so now I'm not sure if this is a code issue, or just a VBA/Excel (2016) or Personal Laptop issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Nick

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt Excel file.  If restarting Excel/rebooting the PC doesn't resolve it, try rebuilding the file (or get a working copy back from one of your users)

Answer (score -1):

That kind of interruption happens for example when the "Control+Pause" key combination is used to stop the execution of the code.

If the key combination is pressed several times, the cache will try to stop the execution the same number of times.

Placing a "DoEvents" function before the loop or just before the "Next" instruction may show you that the interruption is not related to your code.

Best regards,

Fred